# Python psychic guessing game repeats 10 times

Tags: python, loops

I want it so it will randomly generate a number between 1-10 and the user will input their guess. It will then output if it is right or wrong, after 10 rounds it will tell them how psychic they are. I have done most of it but I cannot get it to randomly generate 10 numbers instead it generates 1 number and you can just input that number and get it correct every time if you find that number

```
import random
score=0
random=(random.randint(1,10))

for index in range(10):
    guess=int(input("Choose a number between 1 and 10:"))
    if random==guess:
        score+=1
        print ("Correct, Next")
    else:
        print ("Incorrect, Next")
    
if score==10:
    print("Final score:Super mystic")
elif score>=7:
    print("Final score:Good")
elif score>=5:
    print ("Final score:You need more practice")
else:
    print ("Final score:Dont become a psychic")
```

Comment: Move the `random=(random.randint(1,10))` line into the loop (after the for). You should also rename the `random` variable, or it will create a name conflict with the `random` module.

Comment: There is no name conflict, you just will not be able to access the `random` module by name anymore. There are no name conflicts ever in Python, it will just (re-)use the name you specified for variable. It's still a bad idea to do so, since that can lead to surprises down the line.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to put the `random=(random.randint(1,10))` inside the for loop for it to change with every loop:

```
for index in range(10):
    random=(random.randint(1,10))
    guess=int(input("Choose a number between 1 and 10:"))
```

Then the rest of the code